# Shifting OS from SATA to SSD/HDD

Tags: boot

I dual booted from Windows 11 to Ubuntu 22.04 3-4 weeks back, and i realised that the dev/sda is in the SATA drive.

The OS is very slow for me and I wanted to shift to the Hard Drive holding Windows OS and share that drive between the two. How do I do that?

Comment: Welcome to AU. It'll be possible, but we'll need a lot more information: can you edit your question to show your partitions. It will almost certainly be *much* easier to reinstall Ubuntu to some free space on your SSD - if there's none, you can use Windows tools to shrink the Windows partition, and then install Ubuntu to the free space. As you only installed 3-4 weeks ago, there shouldn't be too much customisation you'd lose I hope. Trying to move your Ubuntu partition from HDD to the SSS would be challenging and probably risky to both OSs.

Comment: Can you let me know exactly what information you need?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you provide us with more information about the partitions you have inside your hard drive, I would say that the best solution is to move the data you want to keep to an external hard drive or a network drive (perhaps using a NAS).

This way you will be able to share the existing information within your hard drives without having to reinstall any of the operating systems that you have installed, but I repeat that I need to see which are the partitions that you have within your hard drive.

P.S:

I can't put this answer in the comments because I don't have enough reputation for it.

Comment: Can you let me know exactly what information you need?